# light-datatable : Add Button to select owner manually in light-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

Need help to suggest a solution for lightning-Datatable -

Need to Add a button **Select Owner** in cell dynamically, so that user can select and display the same manually

[image]

Comment: https://www.infallibletechie.com/2018/04/lightningdatatable-with-buttons-in-2.html does  this answer your question?

Comment: I think his question was to either render text or button dynamically which is not feasible out of the box with datatable component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure you can do this using lightning-datatable as the datatype is defined in the columns but not on data. Alternation solutions are:

1. how about using an action called 'select owner' for each row ?
2. if not, try using slds table markup lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables and render the values dynamically –

Comment: Make sense, Thank you